# How do I prevent audio overlap?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for the title. I couldn't think of a better one. Also, sorry for my English.

I have these four forms. Forms 2-4 have a button that when pressed will play a specific sound from Form 1. There are times that all buttons from the three forms will be pressed almost the same time which causes the audio played from Form 1 overlap each other. How do I prevent this?

Edit:
When all buttons are pressed, I want the audio to "take turns" on being played. "Audio 2, 3" must wait for "Audio 1" to finish playing before they play, and then Audio 3" must wait as well for "Audio 2" to finish. Each "Audio playback" is composed of a SpeechSynthesizer (played using .SpeakAsync) and a SoundPlayer (played using .PlaySync). There's an internet outage on my ISP so I'm just using my phone. It would be quite hard to manually type the code on my phone so sorry for that.

Comment: What's the expected behavior when all buttons are pressed at the same time? Also share the code and show how you are playing sound. To find out more about how to ask a good question, take a look at [ASK].

Comment: I edited my comment :)

Comment: Don't play audio in your forms, but design a dedicate class to do that. Then all forms send audio play request to the same instance of that class, and the instance itself can automatically queue different clips, and play them one by one. In software engineering, we follow such common design practices and principles.

Comment: TIL. Do I just transfer the codes that play the sound to a class and it will automatically queue the playback?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I did a similar thing with a game I made where I had the problem of sounds playing over the top of eachother. In the method that dealt with the sounds, I did this:

```
SoundPLayer sound = new SoundPlayer(..);
SoundPLayer anotherSound = new SoundPlayer(..);

public async void gameMethod()
{
   sound.Play();
   await Task.Delay(400); //length of sound
   //some code ...
   anotherSound.Play();
}
```

This worked for me and just used `await Task.Delay(..)` to add more time around sounds - not sure if this is the way to do this but it might be helpful

Comment: I don't think this would work with in my case because each sound is on a different method.